# Are there any Stack Exchange website(s) for asking questions about animals and insects?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question related to ants. On which Stack Exchange site should I ask? I found Biology.SE.com but its a broad subject. I want a QnA site just for animals and insects.

Comment: That would probably depend on what specifically the question is, as there are many fields that pertain to ants. Can you give us a more specific idea of what your question is about?

Comment: Actually I want a QnA site for animals only. I have a lot of questions about that.

Comment: I've suggested a number of SE sites, but without more details on what question you want to ask, we can't give you a more specific suggestion on what site is best for you.

Comment: I think we need a "Ants and other animals" SE

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Specific questions about animals are on topic on Biology.](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/are-questions-about-specific-animals-on-topic-here) In fact, the [zoology](/questions/tagged/zoology) tag is currently used on 340 questions. [entomology](/questions/tagged/entomology) is used on 199 questions.

[Ants](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=ants) turn up quite a bit there; they are mentioned 148 times.

You won't find a more specific site than [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/), I'm afraid.

---

<sup>I assume [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34761/what-do-ants-do-with-our-finger-nails) is related.</sup>

Comment: Unless the question is about entomophagy, in which case there's Seasoned Advice; and there's also pets (op does mention larger animals; I think people wanting to keep ants as pets would get better advice at biology)

Comment: Garden pests can also be addressed at gardening.

Comment: And the questions about ants in keyboard can be asked at [Lifehacks](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/7149)

Comment: @HomegrownTomato The questions about ants in keyboards should be asked at [Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/256692/whats-the-best-way-to-get-ants-out-of-laptop-keyboards).

Answer (score 8):

This is strongly dependent on what type of question you have to ask.

As @HDE226868 pointed out, for questions about Zoology (animal behavior) and entomology (insects) [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) is your best choice.  I would not worry about your question being 'too broad' - it's already specifically about ants, and I assume you aren't looking to ask something like "how do I write a report on ants", which would not be accepted on *any* SE site.

If you're interested in their effect on your garden, or how they interact with other insects in your garden, [gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) is more ideal, and will cater to specific questions in that regard.

If you're interested in getting an ant farm, [pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) is the site for you, and they'll answer any questions you might have about personally-owned pet ants.

If you want to know about dealing with ants on a camping/picnic trip, [outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) can help you there.

And if you have questions about ants in fiction, there are *several* sites that you can visit to answer your questions: [SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) for giant or otherwise mutant/alien ants from a specific work of fiction, [Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) for writing fictional ants into your own stories, [Movies&TV.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) for TV shows and Movies depicting ants, just to name a few.

Most importantly, if you have several questions about ants that you need to ask, and they don't all fit into one SE, try to divide them into individual questions to ask on the appropriate SE sites - otherwise, you will be flagged for a too-broad question, no matter what SE site you pick.

Comment: this should be the most UV'd question

Answer (score 4):

I once made an Area51 proposal for Wildlife, but it got deleted after inactivity. In a deleted Area51 discussion thread, it was mentioned that [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags) already covers most of that, and your question would likely be on-topic there in the scopes of [zoology](/questions/tagged/zoology), [ecology](/questions/tagged/ecology) or something like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257554/245167

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I'd argue that they cover the same topic but the scope and content are distinctly different.